# SSRS : Empty string from webservice errors even with iif statements

Tags: reporting-services

I am using a web service to get back a value. Which when not needed is empty string. However no matter what I do to try and code for if it is empty is always errors :

```
=iif( Fields!X.Value="","",iif(IsNumeric(Fields!X.Value) ,CStr(CDbl(Fields!X.Value) * 100),""))
```

Thanks for any help
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

```
=IIF(
    IsNumeric(Fields.X.Value),
    Val(Fields.X.Value) * 100,
    ""
    )
```

If X is not numeric you will get and empty string, if X is zero you will get 0 returned and if X is numeric you will get X *100